# Is there any way to transform an array of arrays into JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to transform an array of arrays into a JSON string, but it seems that the method I'm using in my project doesn't work in a specific situation.

I have this code (which doesn't work):

```
$i = 0;
$array = array();
while ($data = $req->fetch()){
    $message = array();
    $message['id_message'] = intval($data['id']);
    $message['id_messaging'] = $data['id_messaging'];

    $array[$i] = $message;
    $i++;
}
$json = json_encode($array);

print_r($array);
var_dump($array);
print_r($json);
var_dump($json);

return $json;
```

When I try to `print_r` or `var_dump` on `$array` or `$json`, then it results in a `502 Bad Gateway` error.

I have tested several things:

- all `$data['...']` values are set (the SQL behind this works properly)
- when I set in `$message` only one piece of information (only `$message['id_message'] = intval($data['id']);` for example), then `json_encode`, `print_r` and `var_dump` work correctly on `$array` and `$json`. For example, I get this result:

```
[{"id_message":203},
{"id_message":201},
{"id_message":199}]
```

In parallel, I have another piece of code which works in the same way for getting other data:

```
$i = 0;
while($data = $req->fetch()){
    $user = array();
    $user['id'] = intval($data['id']);
    $user['name'] = $data['name'];
    $user['surname'] = $data['surname'];
    $user['image'] = $data['image'];
    $user['mail'] = $data['mail'];
    $arrayUsers[$i] = $user;
    $i++;
}

//var_dump($arrayUsers);
//Création de l'adresse
$json = json_encode($arrayUsers);
print_r($json);

return $json;
```

This second piece of code works as expected. It returns this JSON:

```
[{"id":106,"name":"n2","surname":"1","image":"1","mail":"miuig"},
{"id":105,"name":"n1","surname":"1","image":"1","mail":"miuig"},
{"id":94,"name":"n2","surname":"1","image":"miohhu","mail":"miuig"}]
```

Comment: You would normally either just `echo $json;` (may need to add appropriate headers) or if you are using a framework, return it to the framework to handle.

Comment: Already try, same result ```502 bad gateway```

Comment: check error log

Comment: Maybe php needs more RAM ? Try increasing it in php.ini.

Comment: Nothing interesting in error log (just checked), and for the RAM I've already display more data by the past

Comment: what kind of data do you have in `$data['id_messaging']`?

Comment: Why using the `$i` and not just `$array[] = ...`? And if you doing only the second assignment as `$message['id_messaging'] = $data['id_messaging'];` - does it works?